# Why does adding ORDER BY makes the select much faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

First query, 900ms:

```
SELECT * FROM geoip.isp_ipv4 
WHERE INET_ATON(?) BETWEEN start_ip AND last_ip LIMIT 1
```

Second query, 0.5ms:

```
SELECT * FROM geoip.isp_ipv4 
WHERE INET_ATON(?) BETWEEN start_ip AND last_ip ORDER BY start_ip DESC LIMIT 1
```

I wonder why there is so much performance difference.

There could be only one result for a given ip, so the sorting doesn't change the returned row in any way...But why is it so faster?

It's the maxmind geoip db (1.59M rows), this is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `isp_ipv4` (
  `start_ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `asn` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `isp` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `osn` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`start_ip`),
  KEY `last_ip` (`last_ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I'm on MySQL 5.7.17, the same happens in both dev (Windows 10) and production (Ubuntu trusty)

---

The EXPLAINs are identical:

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'isp_ipv4', NULL, 'range', 'PRIMARY,last_ip', 'PRIMARY', '4', NULL, '795214', '50.00', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'isp_ipv4', NULL, 'range', 'PRIMARY,last_ip', 'PRIMARY', '4', NULL, '795214', '50.00', 'Using where'
```

Comment: what show EXPLAIN for both query? of course it possible discuss in theory, but much proper - just look - what mysql think about it

Comment: Added, they are identical

Comment: You sure about the plans? I'd expect one of these queries to involve a sort...

Comment: Yes: http://i.imgur.com/Yt1WzrR.png Anyway the time depends a lot on what ip is asked

Comment: this is what I also think - depending from IP, because it INT - sort could help reduce range

Answer (score 0):

What was the IP?  1.1.1.1 would do best by starting from the beginning.  255.255.255.255 would work better by starting at the end.

The `EXPLAIN` does not say whether the "range" was scanned ascending or descending.  I don't even think `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` would point this out.

So... I think your fast one had a high IP address and did start from the end due to the `ORDER BY`.

[*More*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ip-range-table-performance/) discussion of the intractability of queries like this, plus a solution *if* the ranges are non-overlapping.